# How do people support querying blockchain transactions in a fast way?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, blockchain, smart-contract-wallets

I am thinking to build some business transactions on `blockchain` and have deployed a test network by `ganache` and `truffle`. It works fine and I am able to see the blocks and transactions on `ganache-ui`.

My question is how do people implement querying transaction history from blockchain. When it comes to querying, we usually need to support some filter logic, like:

```
- query transactions whose amount is greater than $100 in desc order
- query transactions during last week
- query transactions from one sender
- query transactions based on ...
```

In case of regular database, we can just construct an sql statement and retrieve from db, then response to frontend. In terms of blockchain, how can we support complicated query? Is there a pattern or something I can think of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You build a local database of all transactions on the specific chain. Then you query your local database. For example, indexing all transactions to PostgreSQL database is popular.

Comment: How do I sync the transactions from blockchain to PostgreSQL? The concern is that blockchain is immutable but people can change data in db. How do we safe guard that?

Comment: PostgreSQL is just a cache and index for the data to look it up fast.